# Spring 4 for storing and retrieving Session from Cookie

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, session-cookies

I am using Spring Security for login. However from what I have read Spring will store the session data in Memory.

If I have multiple machines behind a load balancer then after logins authentications will start to fail because a JSESSIONID will not be present with the other Machine.

One solution which I found was to store this data(session) in cookies and somehow not check for JSESSIONID and only check for expiration date and a symmetric key. The following link [Spring Security - Stateless Cookie Based Authentication with Java Config](https://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.in/2012/02/spring-security-stateless-cookie-based.html) explains how to do this.

However in this solution we have to override all the filters in the chain and maintain it ourself, which is a tedious job.

Is there some easier way to use this cookie based session.

**NOTE**: Some solutions online tell me to use some centralize dataStore but I want to avoid that because that will be an extra network call.